# Setting a factor as a fixed effect or as a random intercept/slope in LMM

Tags: r, mixed-model

Participants completed 4 trials. There are two factors of interest: AROUSAL (High/Low) and LOCATION (Left/Right). Each trial was a combination of each (i.e., HIGH AROUSAL/LEFT, LOW AROUSAL/LEFT, HIGH AROUSAL/RIGHT, LOW AROUSAL/RIGHT). I want to confirm that self-reported arousal scores (likert-style variable, normally distributed) were higher in the High Arousal condition vs the Low Arousal condition. I do not have any reason to suspect that arousal would differ based on location, nor would I have any reason to suspect that there would be an AROUSAL*LOCATION interaction. Basically, this is such a check to confirm that the experimental manipulation in the High Arousal condition worked as intended regardless of the level of the LOCATION factor.

My immediate thought was to run...

lmer(arousal_level ~ AROUSAL*LOCATION + (1|participant)) to account for correlations within individuals.

My understanding of this model would be that LOCATION, as well as AROUSAL*LOCATION interaction, would be treated as co-variates to confirm that arousal levels differed *only* as a function of the AROUSAL manipulation and not the LOCATION manipulation.

Does this seem reasonable, or is there a simpler model that I can use. I get the results that I hypothesized (a significant main effect of AROUSAL and no significant main effects for LOCATION nor the AROUSAL*LOCATION interaction).

Thanks :)

Comment: I think I would want `lmer(arousal_level ~ AROUSAL * LOCATION + (AROUSAL * LOCATION | participant))` as the model, but that isn't a simpler model.